# clflush() in i3 or i7 processors

Tags: caching, assembly, x86

Is it possible to use the clflush instruction/function in i3/i7 processors to the flush the cache and check if the cache is empty or not?? If so - please suggest a correct format of usage (in C directly or inline assembly in C)

I was told that clflush does work properly beyond core 2 duo processors.
I am stating this question after having been redirected from this link (below) ------->

¨[Is there a way to check whether the processor cache has been flushed recently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041271/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-the-processor-cache-has-been-flushed-recently)¨

my results are not matching as expected. This is what I am getting these results:

took 83 ticks

*took 66 ticks*

*flush: took 52 ticks*

took 45 ticks

-------------------> how can the cpu take less ticks after having flushed the cache? (refer to line 2 and 3 of the results that i have gotten)

Comment: sorry would like to rephrase the last line -

Comment: how can the cpu take less ticks after having flushed the cache???

Comment: `clflush` doesn't flush _the cache_ it only flushes a _single cacheline_. To flush the cache in its entirety, you need `wbinvd` but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745665/wbinvd-instruction-usage

Answer (score 5):

`rdtsc` isn't a serializing instruction, as such the measurement is not accurate. As a quick hack you can insert a `cpuid` call, taking care to update the clobber list too:

```
asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx");
```

At least for me, that changed the output to match expectations.